# VBA button not clicking - element not visible error

Tags: vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to click a button using a VBA Chrome driver via Selenium but I get an ElementNotVisibleError

The HTML code for the button is -

```
<button class="base-button" id="primary-button" classnames="primary-button" title="Continue">Continue</button>
```

I've tried to check the element exists and VBA returns TRUE for the following -

```
MyBrowser.IsElementPresent(Findby.ID("primary-button"))
```

but when I try to click the button using the following code, i get the error -

```
MyBrowser.FindElementById("primary-button").Click
```

Comment: `IsElementPresent` is not the same as `IsElementVisible`. Have you tried the latter?  Further, i assume the element IS actually visible in the browser, to yourself?

Comment: You could try another way to access it, by finding it by xPath.

Comment: @C.Peck I'm unsure how to check if the element is visible in VBA, IsElementVisible isn't a command. The element is visible to myself in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To click on the element you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

- Using *FindElementByCss*:

  ```
  MyBrowser.FindElementByCss("button.base-button#primary-button[title='Continue']").Click
  ```
- Using *FindElementByXPath*:

  ```
  MyBrowser.FindElementByXPath("//button[@class='base-button' and @id='primary-button'][@title='Continue' and text()='Continue']").Click
  ```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I use which seems to work in all cases:

```
driver.ExecuteScript "arguments[0].click();", driver.FindElementByXPath("//div[@id='search-engine']/div/div/div[2]")
```

Of course, you can use findelementbywhatever...